# find duplicates within list

Tags: python, numpy

I have got a list containing values like the ones below

```
h = [
    ('red', array([50, 344])),
    ('blue', array([15, 55])),
    ('green', array([1, 1])),
    ('orange', array([3, 7])),
    ('red', array([1, 1]))
]
```

I want to loop through the list and sum the numpy.arrays if the labels are the same. So given the example above since there are two 'red' instances the desired outcome would be the same list but

```
('red', array([ 50, 344])) + ('red', array([1, 1])) = ('red', array([51, 345]))
```

I have tried to have a nested loop like

```
for i in range(0, len(h)):
    for p in range(0, len(h)):
        if (h[i][0] == h[p][0]):
            A = h[i][1] + h[p][1]
```

However, this code sums also the value of the instance `h[i][0]` with itself but I don't want that. I want to do the following - for each instance if the label of other instances without myself is the same then add them to me without adding my value to myself. I hope that's clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using a dictionary to do this:

```
out = {}
for colour, array_ in h:
     if colour in out:
         out[colour] += array_
     else:
         out[colour] = array_
```

You can then get the list back as `out.items()`, which gives me.

```
[('blue', array([15, 55])), ('orange', array([3, 7])), 
 ('green', array([1, 1])), ('red', array([ 51, 345]))]
```

for your example.

This single loop will be more efficient than the double loop you have now, as it processes each item in the list only once.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a line

```
if i==p: 
  continue
```

Furthermore, the `0,` in the range function can be omitted, as it always starts from 0.